# NServiceBus - Long running handler prevents queue from processing any other messages

Tags: nhibernate, ssis, nservicebus

I am running NSB 5 and I am using NHibernate Persistence and have MaximumConcurrencyLevel set to 10.
I have a handler that calls a stored proc that executes an SSIS package.  This package takes a non trivial amount of time to run. I started to notice that whenever this particular message type is handled all other message handling stops.  I noticed via SQL Profiler that the constant querying of the queue table that NSB does in the background stops and that any extra messages put into the queue are not handled even though NSB is only handling one message.

Is there any guidelines or known issues for dealing with handlers that block the queue because database commands take a long time to complete?

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Is sounds like 10 threads are busy, so the endpoint is blocked, can you test this?

I would recommend hosting this message handler in its own process

Make sense?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue by clearing the queue, adding this one message type into the queue, and then while it is handling that message, add additional messages into the queue.  The additional messages are not processed until the first one has completed.   Creating another service, endpoint, and queue for one specific handler is an option of last resort.

Comment: Are you doing this in debug? NServiceBus will process only one message at one time in debug mode, can you try this in a release build?

Comment: Even in the release build it stops processing messages from the queue once it hits the specific message handler.  I also am using a valid license in case that still throttles throughput.

Comment: Any chance you can share your code on github or dropbox? you can email the link to the code directly to me sean.farmar at particular.net

Comment: Can you try and run the host process from command line (not from visual studio) and see if you still see the same behavior? `NServiceBus.Host.exe  /NServiceBus.Production`